# How Should i calculate the balance Amount Using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

```
ID  Type    Type_Description    Amount  Balance
41  85  incoming transaction      100     100
41  55  outgoing transaction     76.6    23.4
41  55  outgoing transaction     23.4       0
41  90  incoming transaction     24.1    24.1
41  55  outgoing transaction    14.19    9.91
41  63  Sweep Off Amount         9.91       0
42  85  incoming transaction      100     100
42  55  outgoing transaction     76.6    23.4
42  55  outgoing transaction     23.4       0
42  90  incoming transaction     24.1    24.1
42  55  outgoing transaction    14.19    9.91
42  63  Sweep Off Amount         9.91       0
```

I want to calculate the Balance from Trs_Amount, where
Transaction_Type==85 denotes an (Initial)incoming transaction and
Transaction_Type==55 an outgoing transaction
Transaction_Type==90 is Provisional Credit which should be added to the Balance (At Transaction level) and
Finally I have to create a row for each ID with the remaing Amount (Sweep Off Amount) Transaction_Type==63.

Comment: Edit your question and define the calculation desired for the balance.  Also, tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I see that balance is updated after every transaction, Is this your stored data or you want this as output? Can you clarify what is the output you need to see from the provided sample data? and if you've written any query already which is not working for you or you want someone to write it for you altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us any schema with which to work, so I have made reasonable assumptions.

Try this:

```
insert into Trs (Trs_ID, Trs_Type, Amount)
select * from (
  select ID, 63, sum(amount * case when Trs_type = 55 then -1 else 1 end)
  from Trs
  group by ID, 63) x
```